# Firebase on Google Cloud Engine: how to setup service accounts?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I have been using Firestore client (with Go) on **Google Cloud Engine** instances for 6 years, with the Google Cloud Engine default **service account**, thanks to these 2 settings:

- I gave such service account the **Editor** role on the Firebase project on the Firebase IAM page in GCP console
- I enabled the **Cloud Datastore** scope on the GCE instance running

I am now trying to setup the **Firebase Cloud Messaging** client (still on Go):

```
ctx := context.Background()
app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
}
client, err := app.Messaging(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error getting Messaging client: %v\n", err)
}
...
response, err := client.Send(ctx, message)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

but I am getting this error:
`Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

I was looking for a **Cloud Messaging** scope (similar to **Cloud Datastore**) on the GCE instance, but I can't find it:

[image]

Then, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66528607/913867) that the **scopes are now legacy**.

So, what is the proper way nowadays to provide Firebase-project access (including Cloud Messaging) to a Google Cloud Engine instance?

Comment: Legacy does not mean do not use. Legacy means the original permissions from long ago - usually before Cloud IAM was developed. It is OK to use legacy permissions in almost all cases. There are some cases, in which Cloud Storage is an example, where newer permissions are better because the method of access control has improved (storage ACLs versus Cloud IAM).

Comment: The scope you need is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging`. Add that when initializing the credentials. Edit your post to show the code you are using.

Comment: @JohnHanley I attached a screenshot with the scopes list on the GCE instance, from where I enabled `Cloud Datastore`, but I can't find the one for messaging.

Comment: A common mistake that developers make is assuming that the VM Access Scopes grant permissions. They don't. They limit permissions. Select `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs` and manage the permissions of the service account via IAM Roles. Summary: IAM Roles grant permissions, VM Access Scopes reduce those permissions. Edit your post and show the code that is creating credentials. That is where you use the scope I mentioned in my other comment.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am not creating any credential in the code. Firebase is supposed to use Application Default Credentials (ADC) https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials.

Comment: @JohnHanley it doesn't feel right to allow full access to all Cloud APIs. Do you know which one on the list is for Cloud Messaging? I have already given Editor access to the service account. I can't give full access to the VM too.

Comment: You misread my comment. You are not granting access to all permissions. VM Access Scopes restrict permissions the service account already has. That is controlled by Cloud IAM roles. If you don't understand my advice, read the documentation on VM Access Scopes and IAM roles. Also, VM Access Scopes does not have a scope for every possible permission.

Comment: @JohnHanley ok, I got it now! so, it seems there is no VM-level restriction for Cloud Messaging. I finally found the way. I had to enable the Firebase Cloud Messaging API using this link: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/fcm.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxxx, where the xxxxx is the GCP project id of my VMs. I had previously enabled it only for the Firebase GCP project but not for the GCP project where I hold the GCE VMs.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am actually now running in a different problem! it seems I am only allowed to send message with the Firebase GCP service account. if I use the GCE service account, it gives me the error: "SenderId mismatch" (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes). So, I guess I have to add the Firebase service account on the machine.

Comment: @JohnHanley I finally found the problem! I had to specify the Firebase GCP project id in the code configuration, as by default it's using the GCE project id.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it's possible to still use the "legacy" scopes with the **Editor** role on the Firebase project for the **GCE service account**.

In case you have two separate GCP projects, one for **Firebase**, one for your **GCE**, make sure that you enable the **Firebase Cloud Messaging API** for both GCP projects:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/fcm.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxxx (where xxxxx is the GCP project id)

You should also specify the Firebase **project id** in the configuration, otherwise you get a "SenderId mismatch" error, as by default it's using the GCE project id.

```
ctx := context.Background()
config := &firebase.Config{ProjectID: "xxxxxxxx"}
app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, config)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error initializing app: %v\n", err)
}
```